# How to reverse proxy host paths to absolute urls using ngix?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a series of local services all running on different ports.
I'd like to expose these services via a nginx reverse proxy.
The routing patterns should follow the pattern:

- `0.0.0.0/app -> locahost:3000`
- `0.0.0.0/api -> locahost:3001`
- `0.0.0.0/db  -> locahost:3002`

I've tried the following:

```
http {
 
    sendfile on;

    upstream app {
      server localhost:3000;
    }

    upstream api {
      server localhost:3001;
    }

    upstream db {
      server localhost:3002;
    }
 
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name 0.0.0.0

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://app
      }

      location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api
      }

      location /db {
        proxy_pass http://db
      }
    }
}
```

The main issue I'm encountering at the moment is that the location is appended to the final path resulting in:

- `0.0.0.0/db` -> `localhost:3002/db`

I'm guessing I could use a rewrite rule, but I'm having trouble getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `/` at the end.

```
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api/
    }
```

From [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI

The same for the others.